# Structure group just to organize other structure groups with publishable pages

Tags: web8.5, structuregroups

In Tridion do we have the possibility to create a SG that behaves like a folder? Like an abstract SG?
We need to create a SG that contains other SG (approximately 1500) so that these elements are not placed right below the root level. However, we need that this SG does not impact the url path. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance

*Example*

[image]

Comment: Before we modify our comments, can you please share why you want some SG to be abstract? Do you want it just to that it looks better in UI of tridion, or do you have some special requirement?

Comment: There is no special requirement. We just want an abstract SG to have a better organization of the items in Tridion (by web section, etc.). We do not want to have more than 1500 structure groups right below the root level.

Comment: Frankly, this is still not clear to me.  I completely understand that you don't want to have over 1500 SGs at the same level in your SG tree.  But in your picture, you still have that, but only inserted an "abstract" SG in the tree. How does that make the situation better?  In general, if you describe the underlying problem, people can help thinking of the best solution.

Comment: Yes, the only thing we want is to keep these 1500 SG inside one abstract SG only with the only intention to keep our pages orginanized per web section (the 1500 pages belong to a concrete section of the website). I guess, as you mention before, this cannot be done in Tridion

Comment: Can you please check my answer, I have updated it based on your comment

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint you, but no, you can only create Structure groups and pages withing a Structure group. Page will always have url based on its structure group path.
If you want some pages not seen in certain publications, you might consider organizing them via Blueprint, so that they are seen in some publications, and not in others.

**UPDATE:**
Based on your comment, there is something that you MIGHT be able to use. You can use blueprint to organize your website. How to achieve this? Basically, you can split your website into multiple websites (Publications). What this means is that  you can set URL per publication, and all SG and pages within that publication have one URL.

For example, your Abstract SG will become Abstract publication with following url: `/root/AbstractURL1/`. Second publication will have url: `root/AbstractURL2/` etc...
[image]

This can help you have better organization of pages, but they ARE SPLIT INTO SEPARATE PUBLICATIONS, with separate content etc... Honestly, this kind of looks like overkill for your request, but this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Structure Groups by definition affect the url of the containing Pages, so to put it simply, no. If it's just for logical grouping then you can explore Bundles as they're just a container for items (they have other features like Workflows but that is irrelevant in this case) but they do not affect the url.

You could try and override the url of the Pages at the publishing or deploying time, but that is sort of asking for trouble.

Comment: Using bundles in this case will not reorganize pages which is the requirement in question, it will just associate them with bundle.

Comment: Yes, that is already stated in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

AS the others have indicated not out of the box.

Given your requirements (or the reasons for them) aren't too clear I'd offer the following high-level considerations

- you can always store pages in a SG and make the SG non-publishable if actually publishing is the issue
- you could catch the publication of these specific pages in an extension point (deployer/storage for example) and redirect the actual page to another location

  - consider the impact to unpublishing
  - consider the impact to the possibility of filename conflicts
  - you could manage the expected location via page metadata
  - consider the implications to editor/publishers given they *may* expect to see/test the page in the "usual" location without knowledge of the redirection method